# When using Tweepy search API to crawl tweets, how to restricts the search scope to a specific user?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

When using Tweepy search API to crawl tweets, how to restricts the search scope to a specific user and a specific language?

The effect is just like advanced searching:

MH370 **lang:en** **from:cnn**

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
tweepy.API.search(q[, lang][, locale][, rpp][, page][, since_id][, geocode][, show_user])
```

with parameters `lang="en"`,`show_user=True` and add `from:cnn` to your query string. See also the [API Reference](http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually I use the search function like this:     `for tweet in Cursor(API(auths[0]).search, q='MH370 from:cnn', count=100, show_user=True, result_type="mixed").items():
            print(tweet.text)` but it do not work. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Does it apply the filters correctly? Or are you getting messages with differnent language tags or user names?

Comment: Is the call succesful or does the response indicate any errors? Can you do a simple query like _MH370_ without filters?

Comment: Simple query is OK. Complex search no.